# YouTube Data API v3 queries per day 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using YouTube Data API v3 for around 1 year now and everything was working fine.
I am using it for a video search in a JavaFX project.

For whatever reason my program wasn't able to query videos today (403 exceeded starting quota) so I took a look at my quotas at Google Developer Console.

I found out that my queries per day are set to 0 and I really don't know why.

Is there a way to reset it to default and does anyone know why this happened?

BR

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take your time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, edit your post, adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help).

Answer (score 0):

You can ask why that happened and request more quota here: https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and seems the issue is explained here:

[Upload via the Youtube via api set to Private (locked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695324/upload-via-the-youtube-via-api-set-to-private-locked)

Not looking forward to verifying the app as it seems to involve countless steps and require your own secure domain name.

Comment: I have verified domain and app but couldn't help.